# "impossible to load image" for php generated image inside css/javascript

Tags: javascript, css, laravel-5, intervention

So in my laravel site I  have this code inside a controller:

```
serveAngledImage($session,$imgId,$angle) {
      [...]

        $maskExists =\Storage::disk('s3')->exists($usrDirectory.$maskFile);

        $maskUrl = \Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl(
            $usrDirectory . $maskFile, now()->addMinutes(12)
        );

        if ($maskExists) {

          $img = Image::make($maskUrl);
          $originalWidth = $img->width();
          $originalHeight = $img->height();
          $img->rotate((-1 * $angle))->crop($originalWidth, $originalHeight)->encode('data-url');
        }
        else {
            $img = null;
        }

        return $img->encoded;

    }
```

which is called by this route:

```
Route::get('/angleImage/{session_id}/{media_id}/{angle}', 'mediacenter@serveAngledImage');
```

So, if I visit this route using the browser, I get the expected result, an encoded image, and if I modify the code to return an `<img>` tag with source `$img` it works perfectly, but when I add it to css (via javascript) as source of a mask, the image is not loaded, and on the webDevelop tools the url is red and there the alert "impossible to load image".

```
var Mask = '-webkit-mask-image: url(/angleImage/'+this.sh_session+'/'+this.image.id+'/'+back.angle+'); -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:block;';
                this.style = Mask;
```

but if I copy paste the link from the css in a new browser tab, it does shoes the encoded image. Hww, if I just print out the data from the pasted link, it something like: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo....

Comment: Are your parameters for url correct?

Comment: I bet they are, or copying and pasting the url from css won't work. Right?

Comment: Have you tried putting url to quotes? `url("/angleImage/'+this.sh_session+'/'+this.image.id+'/'+back.angle+'")`

Comment: I just tried, but it seems that nothing changes. Still alert with "impossible..."

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code... The paths on the background image URLs on CSS are relatives to the path of the file, if you serve the CSS file from a subfolder you will have to change the path of the url.

If the CSS is loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

And the image is served:

http://example.com/images/photo.png

The url should be:

```
background: url('../images/photo.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the controller part, more specifically in the intervention image code. I just replaced:

```
$img->rotate((-1 * $angle))->crop($originalWidth, $originalHeight)->encode('data-url');
```

with

```
$img->rotate((-1 * $angle))->crop($originalWidth, $originalHeight)->response('png');
```

and now everything works.